# change date format from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD with sed

Tags: bash, date, sed, format

I'm doing:

```
sed -e 's|\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-2][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)|\3-\2-\1|g'
```

but when I run the program I'm getting this error:

> "sed: -e expression #4, char 62: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS"

Answer (score 5):

This error generally occurs when capture group have not been escaped properly.

That said, parens for capture groups are escaped in your command, so perhaps you tried to use it with a *Extended Regular Expressions* flag(`sed -r` or `sed -E`) in case you don't need to escape it.

Note that for readability, you can combine character ranges with numerical quantifier:

```
sed -E "s|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\3-\2-\1|" file
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the parens, you need add `\` to make it work as group catching:

```
echo 03/11/2018|sed -e 's|\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-2][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)|\3-\2-\1|g'
2018-11-03
```

In some sed versions like GNU sed, you can add `-E` or `-r` switch, then the escaping will change to opposite way:

```
echo 03/11/2018|sed -E 's|([0-9][0-9])/([0-2][0-9])/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|\3-\2-\1|g'
2018-11-03
```

By deault, you need to use `\(....\)` to catch things into group, and `()` will match parens literally.
With `-E` or `-r` switch however, it's `(...`) to catch groups and `\(\)` to match parens literally.
Btw, `{}` are the same like `()`'s situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "xxx 03/11/2018" |
awk  '
 match($0,/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/){
   if(RSTART!=1){
     val=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
   }
   val=val substr($0,RSTART+6,4)"/"substr($0,RSTART+3,2)"/"substr($0,RSTART,2)
   print val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
echo "xxx 03/11/2018" |                                                               ##Using echo command for printing string and passing its output into awk command.
awk  '                                                                                ##Starting awk program here.
 match($0,/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/){                            ##Using match function for matching regex 2 digits / 2 digits / 4 digits.
   if(RSTART!=1){                                                                     ##Checking if RSTART is NOT equal to 1 then do following.
     val=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)                                                        ##Creating variable val whose value is substring from 1 to RSTART-1, RSTART and RLENGTH are variables which will be SET once a match of regex is found bymatch function of awk.
   }                                                                                  ##Closing block of if condition here.
   val=val substr($0,RSTART+6,4)"/"substr($0,RSTART+3,2)"/"substr($0,RSTART,2)        ##Creating variable val here as per OPs need YYYY/MM/DD by using substring and its index values changing.
   print val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                                                ##Printing value of variable val and substring from value of RSTART+RLENGTH to till end of line.
}'                                                                                    ##Closing block of match now.
```

This will take care of before and after text of the matching date too. Like in above example I have added `xxx` and it will come in before date as follow.

```
xxx 2018/11/03
```

---

---

***OR in case you want to print other lines along with `YYYY/MM/DD`lines then try following.***

```
echo "xxx 03/11/2018" |
awk  '
 match($0,/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/){
   if(RSTART!=1){
     val=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
   }
   val=val substr($0,RSTART+6,4)"/"substr($0,RSTART+3,2)"/"substr($0,RSTART,2)
   print val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   next
}
1 '
```

***NOTE:*** Since my `awk` version is old  so I am using `match($0,/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/` but I believe you could use `match($0,/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/)` if your `awk` is new version.

Comment: @Luis Valdes, could you please do let me know if this helped you?